# How to do something when EOF is reached in the input file?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, eof

I'm trying to track all the functions' signatures in order to check - when all the input file has been scanned - if all of them have been defined and report an error otherwise. To do this I want the scanner to return an `END_OF_FILE` token to the parser in order to call my check procedure, but I get a "token undefined" error, event though I defined it as a token in the parser.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

It is very rarely a good idea to send your own end of file token, and if you chose to do so, you need to exercise considerable care.

Fortunately, it is almost never necessary to do so.

If you want to execute code just before the end of the parse, you can do so in the start production:

```
start: program { /* Code to execute at the end of the parse */ }
     ;
```

If you are using bison, there is a caveat: The code will execute when the parse finishes, whether or not it finishes successfully. In particular, it is possible that there is still an unconsumed token in the input stream. [Note 1]

In many cases, that's not a problem. The error will be detected immediately (unless the action calls `YYACCEPT`) and doing extra checks even if the parse will fail is not usually a problem. In some applications, you might even want this behaviour; for example, if you are parsing an expression embedded in a larger text, and don't want to insist that the parsed context extend to the end of the text.

But if you really need to know whether the parse is complete or not, it is sufficient to check to see that the value of `yychar` is `YYEOF` (see the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Action-Features) for details.) So you could replace the previous with:

```
start: program { if (yychar == YYEOF) {
                    /* Code to execute at the end of the parse */
                 }
                 else {
                    /* There is definitely an error. Probably do nothing. */
                 }
               }
```

---

If you are going to send your own end of file token, you need to ensure that you still maintain the contract between the parser and the lexical scanner, which is that:

- the scanner indicates end of input by returning 0 as a token value; and
- the parser does not request another token after receiving a 0.

Although the lexical scanner can sometimes handle violations of the second condition, it is undefined behaviour and under certain circumstances the generated scanner will segfault or perform other undesirable actions. And since the parser will not understand your custom end-of-file token as indicating end of input, it will continue to request more tokens after receiving it.

That means that you really need to send both your token and the correct `END` token, which means doing something like this:

```
%% 
   /* This code is inserted at the top of yylex */
   static int eof_reached = 0; /* Note: not reentrant */
   if (eof_reached) return END;
 /* ... */
<<EOF>> { eof_reached = 1; return MY_END_OF_FILE; }
```

That will work, but as written the scanner can only be used once since there is no way to reset the eof_reached boolean. You could make it a global, or you could build a re-entrant scanner and add it to the extra data section of the scanner context object. Those are both useful techniques for maintaining scanner state between calls to yylex, but in this particular case I don't think anything is gained by using them because, as mentioned above, it really should almost never be necessary to send a custom end of input token.

---

As for the precise problem you are experiencing:

Without more details, it is impossible to respond to:

> I get a "token undefined" error,

From what? Bison? Flex? the compiler? What does the message say exactly? What line of your code is it referring to? (And did you call the end of file token precisely `END_OF_FILE`?)

#### Notes

1. Because of the way the end-of-input token is handled in the original yacc, this won't happen with the original yacc or byacc and its derivatives. Parser generators with the same end-of-input handling as the original yacc will not normally execute the action associated with the start production unless an end-of-input token has already been encountered.